# How can I obtain the year variable when I do clic in $("#myTab a") in $("#btn-gallery") function

Tags: javascript

I have the next code, I need to obtain the same value of the `year` variable in:

```
let year;

$("#myTab a").on('click', function (e) {

  const year = $(this).attr("aria-controls");

});
```

in my other function:

```
$("#btn-gallery").on('click', function (e) {

    year = ''; // Obtain here 

});
```

Both functions are into the same script tag

Comment: Do not redefine it. Remove the `const`.

Comment: its working, thank you!